# What do I reply to "Elementary, my dear Watson"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, quotes

I was exchanging email with a colleague of mine and she gave me some clues to figure out something. I used those clues and reached to a result and I told her the possible two answers. She then replied saying "Elementary, my dear Watson", which is a phrase taken from "sherlock holmes", but unfortunately I do not watch it and have no idea that what she meant to say and what I'm supposed to reply. 
Help me out.

Comment: It's not up to you to reply.  The next move (assuming her words are not a part of some sort of word puzzle) would be for her to explain what she means -- the phrase basically means "I'm about to explain it to you."

Comment: A side note, the original [author never included such a phrase](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/08/sherlock-holmes-never-said-elementary-dear-watson/) in his "Sherlock Holmes" series.

Comment: Also a note, the phrase comes from the novels, not necessarily the TV show, so any knowledge of the books applies. (And as @NVZ pointed out, the exact phrase was never actually used, but you know what I mean)

Comment: @BruceWayne Psst! You're the Batman, aren't you? ;)

Comment: @BruceWayne, The phrase "Elementary my Dear Watson" does not appear in any work by Conan Doyle.  It first appeared in the series of films with Basil Rathbone, which also introduce other non-Doyle features such as the Deerstalker hat and the curved pipe.

Comment: @Chenmunka - ah, whoops yeah. I should have been more clear and said never used by Sir Doyle

Comment: If someone tells me "elementary, ...", I might respond saying "Indeed, Mr Holmes". Enough said.

Comment: I haven't replied anything to her mail and neither have I received any further mail.